# Type error switching from .m to .mm

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c

I encountered this error:

```
cannot convert 'V_DTLPROMO_BTN_FN_T' to 'V_DTLPROD_BTN_FN_T' in argument passing
```

in code line:

```
[ m_vPromoDetails   changeButton : V_DTLPROMO_BTN_2 btnFn : V_DTLPROMO_BTN_FN_ADD ];
```

Both arguments are of type `V_DTLPROMO_BTN_T` & `V_DTLPROMO_BTN_FN_T` which is are enum declared in the `.h` file. Things were working fine until I changed the implementation file extension to `.mm` from `.m` to accommodate some C/C++ related code.

Prototype declaration

```
- ( void )changeButton : ( V_DTLPROMO_BTN_T    )button 
             btnFn : ( V_DTLPROMO_BTN_FN_T )btnFn
```

Enum definitions

```
    typedef enum
{
  V_DTLPROMO_BTN_FN_NONE        =   0,   /**< None                       */
  V_DTLPROMO_BTN_FN_RECOMMEND   =   1,   /**< Recommend                  */
  V_DTLPROMO_BTN_FN_ADD         =   2,   /**< Add                        */
  V_DTLPROMO_BTN_FN_DELETE      =   3,   /**< Delete                     */
  V_DTLPROMO_BTN_FN_LOCATE      =   4,   /**< Locate                     */
  V_DTLPROMO_BTN_FN_BUY_NOW     =   5,   /**< Buy Now                    */
  V_DTLPROMO_BTN_FN_SHOPPED     =   6,   /**< Shopped                    */
  V_DTLPROMO_BTN_FN_TWEET       =   7,   /**< Locate                     */
  V_DTLPROMO_BTN_FN_NUM         =   8    /**< Number of function choices */

} V_DTLPROMO_BTN_FN_T;


    typedef enum
{
  V_DTLPROMO_BTN_1     =   0,   /**< Button: 1         */
  V_DTLPROMO_BTN_2     =   1,   /**< Button: 2         */
  V_DTLPROMO_BTN_3     =   2,   /**< Button: 3         */
  V_DTLPROMO_BTN_NUM   =   3    /**< Number of buttons */

} V_DTLPROMO_BTN_T;
```

Comment: Can you include the prototype from the header file?

Comment: I would expect you have exactly what it tells you is happening - a type mismatch someplace.  Doublecheck all of the prototypes and enumerations to make sure they're correct.

Comment: You probably need an extern "C" if you're using .mm and .m files otherwise some would get C linkage and others would get C++ linkage. Oh, and I'm assuming from the name that the type is a function pointer.

Comment: @carl I have already got every thing running if i don't include the new cpp stuff in obj c classes ,thus that rules out type mismatch.A similar kind of code snippet even compiled in a different class without any errors.

Comment: @steven yes it is a function pointer but how to make sure all the classes get c++ linkage?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `V_DTLPROMO_BTN_FN_T` in your .h file?

Comment: @pavel,i have added it to the question

Comment: Where is V_DTLPROD_BTN_FN_T coming from?  This is not the same as the other two PROMO enums listed.  I'd do a search for the type it thinks it is trying to convert to see if you can figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`V_DTLPROD_BTN_FN_T` is an enum declared in another class.My `detailpromo` class was somehow getting confused by that enum in `detailprod` class.I noticed that the function names were same in both the classes ,so I tried to change the function name from `changeButton` to `changeButtonForPromo`.That did the trick and errors were removed.Still havent got the technical explanation for that.